# Skinny pipe entering toilet siphon flush

Tags: toilet

The flapper came off on our siphon flush, so I bought a new one.  I fitted it but it was leaking badly.

When I looked properly, I noticed the inner pipe delivering the water to the toilet from the cistern was not flush with siphon flush.  This means the siphon permanently fills up with water as below;
[image]

Is that normal? Should the connection not be on the outside of the cistern?

Answer (score 1):

I missed it as it was hidden in a decorative metal feature on the toilet.

There is a gasket and a kind of plastic locking plate specifically to tackle this issue.

Comment: I'm a bit late, but thanks for the answer. Would you mind adding a picture of the hidden feature to help future visitors? Thanks.

Comment: Also, please give yourself a check mark so others know this one has a working solution.